# How to group by two column with swapped values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group by columns where the commutative rule applies.

For example 
`column 1`, `column 2` contains values `(a,b)` in the first row and `(b,a)` for another row, then I want to group these two records perform a group by operation.

**Input:**

```
From    To  Count
a1      b1  4
b1      a1  3
a1      b2  2
b3      a1  12
a1      b3  6
```

---

**Output:**

```
From    To  Count(+)
a1      b1  7
a1      b2  2
b3      a1  18
```

I tried to apply group by after swapping the elements. But I don't have any approach to solve this problem. Help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) for sorting each row:

```
cols = ['From','To']
df[cols] = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[cols], axis=1))
print (df)
  From  To  Count
0   a1  b1      4
1   a1  b1      3
2   a1  b2      2
3   a1  b3     12
4   a1  b3      6

df1 = df.groupby(cols, as_index=False)['Count'].sum()
print (df1)
  From  To  Count
0   a1  b1      7
1   a1  b2      2
2   a1  b3     18
```

Comment: You can just do `df[cols] = np.sort(df[cols], 1)`